# Missing /var/run/php-fpm/php7.4-fpm.sock or /var/run/php-fpm/

Tags: php, fpm, php-7.4

Using: Ubuntu 20.04
PHP starts failed **because missing /var/run/php-fpm/php7.4-fpm.sock & /var/run/php-fpm/php7.4-fpm.pid**.
Heres the details: (feedback from `systemctl status php7.4-fpm.service`)

> ● php-fpm7.4[3465899]:ERROR: unable to bind
> listening socket for address '/var/run/php-fpm/php7.5-fpm.sock': No such
> file or directory (2)

> ● php-fpm7.4[3465899]:ERROR: unable to bind
> listening socket for address '/run/php-fpm/php7.5-fpm.pid': No such
> file or directory (2)

I checked "/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf", but there is the following code in the file:

```
;listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php7.4-fpm.sock
```

Comment: `I wanted to find that .sock file, but I didn't even see the "/var/run/php-fpm" folder` Create it.

Comment: If it is 7.4 then you should have `listen = /var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock`
Restart the service using `service php7.4-fpm restart` sudo if you need too.  and also restart nginx/apache2

Comment: @dai007uk I tried, but nothing happened. Starting PHP7.4-fpm & Apache2 still failed.

Comment: @tkausl Do you mean to create that .sock file or create that folder? I made that folder and restarted php7.4-fpm, but nothing happened.

Comment: The folder. If it still didn't work, look at the status again, the error message should be different.

Comment: @tkausl  It's the same...ERROR: unable to bind listening socket for address '/var/run/php-fpm/php7.4-fpm.sock': No such file or directory (2)

Answer (score 0):

> php-fpm7.4[3465899]:ERROR: unable to bind listening socket for address '/var/run/php-fpm/php7.5-fpm.sock': No such file or directory

**First problem**: it is searching for `php7.5-fpm.sock` instead of `php7.4-fpm.sock`

But since you confirmed that your `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` indeed has `listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php7.4-fpm.sock`, I will just assume the `php7.5-fpm.sock` naming was handled/adjusted.

**Second problem**: the `.sock` file does not exist when your FPM is running. To solve this, run the following:

```bash
mkdir -p /var/run/php-fpm
touch /var/run/php-fpm/php7.4-fpm.sock
```

NOTE:
If you get permission denied, you should use `sudo` for the above commands.

Then restart your PHP-FPM service.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Update the Fast CGI path location in the `default` nginx configuration, in the path ***/etc/nginx/sites-available/default***

**fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;**

By default it was *php7.4-fpm* in my case!

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
```

It was also throwing 502 Bad Gateway error while trying to run a PHP file.,

Answer (score -3):

Type in:

```
cd /run
sudo mkdir php 
sudo mkdir php7.4-fpm
cd /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/
cp www.conf www.conf.backup
vi www.conf
```

Find following code:
line 36:

> listen = /run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock

change it to:

> listen = 127.0.0.1:9000

line 133:

> listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php7.4-fpm.sock

Remove that line, save that file, and type in:

```
sudo service php7.4-fpm stop
sudo service php7.4-fpm start
```

Thanks:
**@tkausl
@dai007uk**

Comment: Turning off a functionality is not the way to fix it.